# update a has_one relation model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_information, :dependent => :destroy
  attr_accessible :email, :name
end
```

and

```
class UserInformation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :address, :business, :phone, :user_id
end
```

after created the user,  I created the user information using the new and the create action of my controller:

```
  def new
         @user = User.find(params[:id])
         @user_information = @user.build_user_information

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user_information }
    end
  end



def create
    @user_information = UserInformation.new(params[:user_information])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user_information.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user_information, notice: 'User information was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @user_information, status: :created, location: @user_information }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user_information.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

everything works fine, but when I try to update the record I get this error:

```
RuntimeError in User_informations#edit

Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

Here are the edit and the update action of my user_information controller

```
    def edit
        @user_information = UserInformation.find(params[:id])
      end 

  def update
    @user_information = UserInformation.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user_information.update_attributes(params[:user_information])
        format.html { redirect_to @user_information, notice: 'User information was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user_information.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I thought I only have to find the record and edit, but no. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Spelling of `User_informations#edit` is confises me. Can you show controller class name and filename.

Comment: ok the controller name is UserInformationsController, the file name is user_informations_controller and the route to edit the record is http://localhost:3000/users/1/user_informations/1/edit

Comment: So your link helper should be `users_user_information(user_id, user_info_id)`. Name of the helper can be different but pay attention to the two arguments.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry ck3g, I new in rails :s I don't understand what you mean with the helper and the arguments.

Comment: Could you provide, please, line with `link_to "edit"` and `rake routes | grep 'user_informations#edit'`?

Comment: well I didn't try from the view, I go to this url localhost:3000/users/1/user_informations/1/edit but the link_to in the view is this <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_information_path(@user_information) %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove `belongs_to :user` from `UserInformation`
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_one-association

**update after discussion**:

Your link helper should takes two arguments with `@user` at first position. (You can see it from result of `rake routes | grep user_information`)

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_information_path(@user, @user_information) %>
```

Second of all in your controller

```
params[:id] # => @user.id
params[:user_information_id] # => @user_information.id
```

So you should change `find` to

```
@user_information = UserInformation.find(params[:user_information_id])
```

Comment: I can't do that. I need this association

Comment: Thanks ck3g, I try your suggestion, but I still have the same error when I try to update the record

Comment: I'm sorry ck3g, but what you mean with 
params[:id] 
params[:user_information_id] in all my controllers???